# Vuetify: v-tabs not showing the content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Following the [official](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs/#right) docs the code does not work on my machine, the result is simply showing nothing.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-tabs fixed-tabs> 
      <v-tab>Reservas </v-tab>
      <v-tab>Reservar </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>

    <v-tab-item> Any content </v-tab-item>
    <v-tab-item> Any Content too </v-tab-item>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: "Reservations"
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Put the v-tab-item inside the v-tabs element. Alternatively, see https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tabs-items/

Comment: You're welcome, good luck!